# T-SQL and wildcard string matching performance on large table

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I've got a bit of a problem with T-SQL, I'm basically in a position where I have to run a whole bunch of queries like:

```
SELECT TOP 30 * FROM [table]
    WHERE firstfield IS NOT NULL
    AND secondfield IS NOT NULL
    AND (firstfield LIKE '%substring%' OR secondfield LIKE '%substring%')
```

This is being run from a C#.NET program with the timeout on the `SqlCommand` set to 90 seconds and for most queries (that search for terms that are rare or non-existent) it hits the timeout.

The problem with this is of course that it's extremely slow but the data has to be fetched. Once fetched all the returned `firstfield`s and `secondfield`s are just concatenated together (this larger string is stored and analyzed by the program).

I'm currently running this on my work laptop as the production server that has this data slows down too much when running thousands of these queries. When running on the production server I get results back about 30% of the time, on my laptop (with only 4 GiB of RAM and a regular 2.5" spinning rust hard drive) it's closer to 10%.

So, is there any way for me to either speed this up or is my best bet to just up the timeout and leave it running for weeks until it is finished? I've considered just building a data fetcher program that just dumps the results into a separate table along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    keyword VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    returneddata VARCHAR(MAX), -- Or possibly a TEXT field.
)
```

That way I could leave the fetcher program running and just have my main program query this table. But honestly, I'd rather just figure out a way of making the queries run faster (or another way of making the queries). I just really hope I'm being a dummy and that I've missed out on some obvious way to make this run faster...

Comment: Could you add some more details please? e.g. An example of substring and the data it is filtering. It would also be helpful if you could explain what the data is for and how you think the data fetcher program can deliver. Is it possible to rearrange the data in the db through this data fetcher so that it is easier to query??

Comment: The substrings are mostly "long-tail" type things, words and short phrases that are fairly uncommon. The data is being mined for statistical analysis and the advantage of using a separate fetcher would be that I could create a key:value-type source so I wouldn't have to do such expensive queries with the main program, it would make fetching and processing for the main program a lot easier to work on (since initial data imports wouldn't take 90+ seconds per substring).

Comment: What type are `firstfield` and `secondfield`, and what indexes do you have on the table? For example, if you don't have a clustered index and don't use `ORDER BY`, which 30 rows you're getting may vary from one query to another.

Comment: VARCHAR(800) on both of them. There are a whole bunch of indexes including non-clustered indexes for both `firstfield` and `secondfield` (ascending order). Generally exactly which records I get back isn't all that important, for the vast majority of keywords there will be fewer than 30 records, it's just a limit for the few keywords that have hundreds of records.

Comment: How up to date do you need the query results?   There are lots of 3rd party (some open source) systems for doing full text indexing, but they tend to all lag behind the main database a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How quick does it need to be? There's a couple of options: diddle around with indexes to improve disk i/o (which won't give you the best performance as normal indexes aren't optimised for sub-string searched)... or use full-text search (a bit more work to set-up, but will give you a huge performance boost as they are optimised for subn-string searches). If this is an operation that that's going to happen regularly, then you'll seriously want to use full-text search as anything else is just storing trouble up further down the line. If it's just for a one-off job, then you *might* get away with basic indexes (it depends what other constraints you've got), but that's by no means guranteed... however I'll cover both here just for completeness.

First option... have you got any indexes against these columns table? If you haven't got appropriate indexes then it will be a lot slower than it needs to be as it has to fetch the data straight out of the data page. If not, then there's two options: create a composite index on (firstfield, secondfield) then see if that does anything.

Alternatively create two indexes, one on (firstfield), the other on (secondfield) and split your query into two queries, one that queries firstfield only, the other that queries secondfield only.

However neither of these will be blindingly quick as normal indexes are not optimised for substring searches: any speed-up will simply be due to improved disk i/o as SQL Servfer won't need to read as much data from disk to find matching rows (it'll just read index pages rather than the full data page ... however it still needs to do the same amount of work once it's got the data off disk to then find the rows).

If you do need it to be lightning quick, then you're better off investigating [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx), which will then allow you to use the [`CONTAINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) keyword instead. This will allow you to do very quick sub-string searches.

Comment: With a wildcard search as described, indexes on these columns will be pretty much pointless.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `FULLTEXT` indexes, unfortunately I'm having some issues getting it to work. From what I understand I need to first create a `UNIQUE` index (which I assume rules out my current indexes on both `firstfield` and `secondfield` as those are non-unique and for some reason can't be converted to `UNIQUE` without sql server throwing an error about `[...] the duplicate key value is ()`).

Comment: With a bunch of tweaking, reinstalling SQL Server (since it didn't allow me to just add full text search, it required a reinstall according to some doc I found on MS' website) and copying the relevant data to a separate table I was able to get Full text search working, the performance difference is staggering to say the least, queries that would take 90+ seconds before now take less than five seconds. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can consider enabling full text and then use freetext in your query instead of wildcard
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx

Comment: This is the only way to do a "leading wildcard" search correctly

Answer (score 2):

If you have a wildcard on both sides of the string (e.g. `%x%` not simply `x%`) then SQL Server cannot use any statistics to optimise the query.

Full text search is a likely solution, but I notice the `LIKE` does not run afoul of the documented [limitations on creating indexed views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx). You could create a view and index it for fairly fast results.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise using the second table approach.

You can run the "fetcher" program as a background task/overnight etc.

Although you may be able to optimise the above query, it will never be as performant as the key/value approach you mention, providing of course you are able to index the 2nd table appropriately.

Use of a 2nd table, is very similar to denormalising which is a standard practice for improving responses to user requests or reporting, so what you suggest is not in any way a hack.

At the end of the day, your users will appreciate the faster response times.

Answer (score 0):

Since both fields are `varchar(800)`, you can do the following:

```
SELECT TOP 30 * FROM [table]
    WHERE (
        coalesce(firstfield, '') LIKE '%substring%' OR
        coalesce(secondfield, '') LIKE '%substring%')
```

This may not help much regarding performance, but I would try both and have a look at the execution plan of the queries. That should tell you what gets used in terms of indices and the like, I've always found that very helpful.